# SEVERE: Unable to read class - Struts2 Annotations

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I am trying to to create a struts project without the struts.xml file and only using annotations. This is not my idea, I am following the example at this URL: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_annotations.htm

I think I have everything correct in terms of replicating the example as described in the tutorial. When I run the application however I receive a 500 error, shown as the last image below.

Project structure is as follows:
[image]

The Employee.java source code is below this sentence.

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.*;

@Results({

    @Result(name="success", location="/success.jsp"),
    @Result(name="input", location="/index.jsp")
})

public class Employee extends ActionSupport {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Action(value="/empinfo")
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @RequiredFieldValidator(message="The name is required")
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @IntRangeFieldValidator(message="Age must be in between 28 and 65", min="29", max="65")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}
```

My `web.xml` file is coded like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>StrutsAnnotations</display-name>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

The error I receive when building and deploying to the Tomcat server.
[image]
This error says the class was not read for some reason. The class is the Employee.java shown above in the screenshot of the project and in the source-code. I cannot figure out why the class was not read. Does anyone have any idea?

This is what is displayed after deploying the application and starting up the server.
[image]

This is the 500 error I receive when clicking the 'Submit' button.
[image]

Comment: `To start using annotations in your project, make sure you have included following jar files in your WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder`, that tutorial says. So do you have `asm-x.y.jar`? However, I recommend using maven for dependencies instead.

Comment: Thank-you for the reply. Since no one seems to know what is going wrong I am trying a new tutorial.